# check group product in cart programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, grouped-products

how to check the `group product` is in cart or not. i am adding into with below code.

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$params = array('super_group' => $pro);
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get cart items, then in loop you can check parent Id by child for item (product):

`Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove it by item id

```
$itemId = 'Your Item Id';
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->removeItem($itemId);
```